# I clicked a link in an email message. What should I do now?

Tags: email-spoofing

I got a message that looked like an ad from Microsoft. At the end, there was a message saying "You can simply WIPE Out your email from Mailing List  click here". I clicked. I got to a page this webpage:  `http://gokk.tezharimirch.com/`  which is obviously not from Microsoft. The page just showed an "404" message - I did not fill any form or do anything else.

What should I do now to protect my computer?

Answer (score 2):

That sub-domain is still working/alive so there's a chance it would of still have deployed something then 404'ed.

Currently, a scan performed on that sub-domain shows it is clean, so it most likely did contain something bad at a point but was then removed. You can do URL scans with online tools like virustotal.com .

Just to be on the safe side, you should just scan your system for anything dangerous with anti-malware/anti-spyware tools.